# .htaccess ExpiresDefault 1 day

Tags: apache, .htaccess

If I add only these 2 lines to the .htacces file, will all the files on the website be kept in the cache for 1 day?

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
```

Is it enough and it works?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ExpiresActive On
> ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
> ```

If you have no other overriding directives then these directives do indeed instruct the browser to cache the response for 1 day, by sending back the appropriate `Expires` and `Cache-Control: max-age` HTTP response headers. (`Expires` is required for old browsers. All modern browsers will use the `Cache-Control` header instead.)

> Is it enough and it works?

Whether it is "enough" is entirely dependent on the nature of your site. Depending on your site, some responses perhaps shouldn't be cached at all, whilst other static resources should be cached for much longer.

And it's entirely possible you have other directives or even a front-end proxy or CDN that overrides these response headers.